# Is the conjunction of all necessary statements sufficient? What about the converse?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

A necessary condition for consequent $q$ is a proposition $p$ such that:

$$\neg p \implies \neg q$$

let $P:= \{p_i: \neg p_i\implies \neg q\}$

What I want to know is if

$$\bigwedge_{p_i\in P} p_i \implies q $$

Here's my attempt at this problem:

Let $P$ be defined as above, which means that $P$ is the set of *all* necessary propositions for $q$.

Now, if we assume that
$$\bigwedge_{p_i\in P} p_i \implies q $$

is false, is means that

$$\exists r\notin P: \neg r \implies \neg q$$

However, this is means that $r\in P$ since it is also a necessary condition. We have deduced a contradiction by denying the truth of the statement  "the truth of all necessary conditions implies the truth of the consequent".

Conversely, a sufficient statement is defined as:

$$p \implies q$$

For this, I am interested in the statement:

$$\neg \bigvee_{p_i \in Q} p_i\implies \neg q$$

Where $Q:= \{p_i: p_i \implies q\}$

Along similar lines, it appears that denying the statement "if no sufficient conditions hold, then not q$ requires that there be an additional statement whose  truth implies q...but this is a contradiction, since we area assuming that we have already identified all sufficient conditions.

**Question**

If we assume that the universe is deterministic and that $q$ is not trivially true or false (a priori), then are my arguments correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are considering "causality" and some sort of "natural law"; if so, propositional logic and the *conditional* ($\to$) are ot the "right tools" for your job.

Simplifying the example, from the fact that $(p_1 \land p_2) \to q$ is *false*, we can derive that:

> $p_1 \land p_2 \land \lnot q$ is *true*.

From this you conclude that there must be some "missing" condition $r$ responsible for the fact that $q$ has not "happened".

In terms of logic, this is not necessary; if $q$ is an "impossible" condition (a *contradiction*), you can "add" a false premise $t$ whatever and what you get:

> $(p_1 \land p_2 \land t) \to q$

will be *true*.

The truth-functional [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Philosophical_problems_with_material_conditional) is used in the analysis of the relation of [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence), but gives "unpleasant" results if we try to use it to analyse the *causation* relationship between events.

Comment: +1: Thanks for pointing out the error. As someone with a scientific background, I think causal reasoning pervades my logic. I've read that the material conditional is problematic, and now I can see why!

Comment: @Bey - you can see [Counterfactual Theories of Causation](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-counterfactual/) and [Conditionals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/).